# AlamoFire adding extra string when using a POST call

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, alamofire

When when I use a POST using AlamoFire one of the String  param's has added characters  to it? Any idea?

```
let email = emailText.text

Alamofire.request("https://xxxx", method: .post, parameters: ["subscribed": true,"address": email],encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).validate()
        .log().responseJSON {
        response in
```

This is what the params look like

```
address=Optional%28%22Adam%40yahoo.com%22%29&subscribed=1
```

This is what it looks like if I hard code the email to

```
let email = "adam@yahoo.com"
```

Result

```
address=adam%40yahoo.com&subscribed=1
```

Comment: Change `email` to `email!` (if you are sure it isn't `nil`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `email` is wrapped into an optional (nullable value). You might want to unwrap it first:

```
guard let email = emailText.text else {
  // Handle the case where there is no email
  return
}
...
```

Comment: `"Handle the case where there is no email"` The else conditional of the guard will never be executed. Better to use `emailText.text!` directly. The UITextField text property  default value
 is an empty string. Even if you assign nil to it it will return an empty string right after it.

Comment: Not quite actually. You should be very careful about using `!`, since it will crash if it's nil. This may not be the case, but keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: You can test it yourself

Comment: Btw you can use `UIKeyInput` property called `hasText` which is made exactly for this. `if emailText.hasText {` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext